# Is there a fastest way to process image filters in OpenCV.js?

Tags: javascript, image, opencv, filter

#### My goal

- Finding the fastest techniques to implement many image filters using opencv.js
- Only use opencv for javascript because I will use it on browser and node.js
- Performance(speed) under 10ms possibly (total time: all image filters)

I am trying to implement image filter features using opencv.js. It is important to the `performance(speed)` when changing values of image filters because I need to provide the filters with a `track bar`(like input range) in `real time`.

Are other else any fastest ways like WebGL or SVG Filter? Or did I use opencv.js the wrong way?

#### Excluded techniques:

- CSS
- WebGL(OpenGL)
- SVG Filter(feComponentTransfer, feFuncR, feFuncB, feFuncG, ...)

Because I will use these features on Node.js with CUDA(Nvidia) as well.

#### Try

I have tried the 4 ways like this:

- **for loop with channels (30ms)**
- convertTo (60ms)
- convertScaleAbs (60ms)
- filter2D (120ms)

##### (Updated: Added code examples)

How to check the speed(ms):

```js
console.time('xxxFilter');
// for loop with channels or convertTo or convertScaleAbs or filter2D
// included 'cv.imshow(canvasOutput)'
someFilterFunc();
console.timeEnd('xxxFilter');
```

It is not included render painting time on the browser.

1. for loop with channels

```js
function brightnessWithChannels(dst, value) {
  cv.cvtColor(dst, dst, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB);

  const channels = new cv.MatVector();
  cv.split(dst, channels);

  const alphaRatio = 0.3 / 100;
  const alpha = 1 + value * alphaRatio;

  const deltaRatio = 40 / 100;
  const delta = value * deltaRatio;

  const channelR = channels.get(0);
  const channelG = channels.get(1);
  const channelB = channels.get(2);

  const pxR = channelR.data;
  const pxG = channelG.data;
  const pxB = channelB.data;

  for (let i = 0; i < pxR.length; i++) {
    const r = alpha * pxR[i] + delta;
    pxR[i] = Math.max(Math.min(r, 255), 0);

    const g = alpha * pxG[i] + delta;
    pxG[i] = Math.max(Math.min(g, 255), 0);

    const b = alpha * pxB[i] + delta;
    pxB[i] = Math.max(Math.min(b, 255), 0);
  }

  cv.merge(channels, dst);

  channelR.delete();
  channelG.delete();
  channelB.delete();
  channels.delete();

  cv.cvtColor(dst, dst, cv.COLOR_RGB2BGR);
}
```

2. convertTo

```js
function brightnessWithConvertTo(src, dst, value) {
  const alphaRatio = 0.3 / 100;
  const alpha = 1 + value * alphaRatio;

  const deltaRatio = 40 / 100;
  const delta = value * deltaRatio;

  src.convertTo(dst, -1, alpha, delta);
}
```

3. convertScaleAbs

```js
function brightnessWithConvertScaleAbs(dst, value) {
  const alphaRatio = 0.3 / 100;
  const alpha = 1 + value * alphaRatio;

  const deltaRatio = 40 / 100;
  const delta = value * deltaRatio;

  cv.convertScaleAbs(dst, dst, alpha, delta);
}
```

4. filter2D

```js
function brightnessWithFilter2D(dst, value) {
  const factor = value / 100; // -1.0 ~ 1.0

  /**
   * https://docs.rainmeter.net/tips/colormatrix-guide/
   * [R 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
   * [G 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
   * [B 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
   * [A 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
   * [W factor, factor, factor, 0, 1]
   */
  const kernelMatrix = [
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
    factor, factor, factor, 0, 1
  ];
  const kernel = cv.matFromArray(5, 5, cv.CV_32FC1, kernelMatrix);
  cv.filter2D(dst, dst, -1, kernel);
  kernel.delete();
}
```

[This is the full html example(codesandbox)](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-dijkstra-85qvqw?file=/index.html)

- It is slowest: for loop with ptr (excluded above list)
- ref: the [opencv.js document](https://docs.opencv.org/4.6.0/d5/d10/tutorial_js_root.html)

Environment

- Browser: Chrome, Safari
- OpenCV JavaScript 4.6.0 (https://docs.opencv.org/4.6.0/opencv.js)
- Image resource(maximum 1600*1600px)

etc) C++ (2ms)

I ran this code on node.js with C++ addons

```cpp
static void brightness_slice(FilterContext *ctx, void *arg, int job, int nb_jobs)
{
    int start = (ctx->height * job) / nb_jobs;
    int end = job == nb_jobs - 1 ? ctx->height : (ctx->height * (job+1)) / nb_jobs;
    int line = ctx->width * 4;

    const float contrast = ((float)abs(ctx->nValue)) * 0.5;
    const float alpha = (259 * (contrast + 255)) / (255 * (259 - contrast));
    const float delta = 128 * (1 - alpha) + (((float)ctx->nValue) / 300 * 255);
    int i, j;

    for (i = start; i < end; i++) {
        uint8_t *p = ctx->data + i * line;
        for (j = 0; j < ctx->width; j++, p+= 4) {
            p[0] = CLAMP_RGB(alpha * ((float)p[0]) + delta);
            p[1] = CLAMP_RGB(alpha * ((float)p[1]) + delta);
            p[2] = CLAMP_RGB(alpha * ((float)p[2]) + delta);
        }
    }
}
```

When I checked the performance above ways(in html), the `for loop with channels` was the fastest among them. It is nice. However, I want to the speed be close to `speed <= 10ms` because it is still slow(`30ms`) for users in real time.

I even have to mix many image filters like this: brightness + contrast + saturation + blur + sharpness + ...

Comment: Please post the code of your functions here in the question, so that people don't have to hunt it down in your sandbox. Anyhow, processing a 2.5 MPix image will take its time. Do you have any reference for your benchmark ? How long does it run in C++ for example ? Also 30ms processing makes for ~30fps live view, whats wrong with that ?

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre]

Comment: @nick

Thanks for the comment :) I added the code examples and the performance check method I used.
C++ brightness example measured 2ms on node.js.
When I used image filter with WebGL or SVG Filter on the browser (There is no example... I could not measured them), it was so fast like native language(C++).

Comment: I'm really not sure why convertScaleAbs() would be slower then your hand-rolled loop. (But not am JS expert either.) If you want to speed up option 1, two things you could try: (a) Convert RBG2HSV instead of BGR, then only scale the V-Channel (the brightness) and back with HSV2RGB. (b) Keep scaling all three Channels, but drop the conversion alltogether. You don't need it, as you work on all three channels individualy anyways.

Comment: Good advices :). I will try 2 options.